# type 'List<Object>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>' of 'function result' where

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to map objects to actual widgets but keep getting this error

```
type 'List<Todo>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Todo>' of 'function result' where
  Todo is from package:todoapp/view/main_page.dart
  Todo is from package:todoapp/dto/todo.dart
```

Todo item is a simple class(todo.dart)

```
  const Todo({required this.id, required this.name, required this.isDone});

  final int id;
  final String name;
  final bool isDone;
}
```

and here is a mapping function

```
  List<Widget> getTodoListItems(List<Todo> todos) {
    return todos.map((todo) {
      return TodoListItem(todo: todo);
    }).toList();
  }
```

List view is initialized like that

```
...
 ListView(children: getTodoListItems(todos))
 ...
```

When I move the content of `todo.dart` to file with widget everything works fine but this is not quite of a solution for me, because this class is shared across different widgets.

Can someone please explain to me what is going on here? Apparently, this is the same object thus the same type, or at least it looks so

Edit:
There are many questions that look similar to this one, but they have different types which at least makes sense

Comment: it seems that you have two Todo classes in your app and you're having name conflicts with them

Comment: That's what I've thought at first. But Nope. This is the only Todo class in project

Comment: not even a stateless of stateful widget called todo inside view/main_page? if so I'm clueless, sorry

Comment: Well, it is used in different widgets(both statefull and stateless), but the class itself is declared in separate file

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was silly, but seems like flutter cached something. Restarting a project and reinstalling the app helped